# Spring Kafka batch error handler - DeSerialiser Error handling with manual commit

Tags: java, spring-kafka

My service is stuck in infinite loop when trying to handle JSON deserializer error. My service is using manual_immediate acknowledge mode with auto offset reset as false. I am using `acknowledge.acknowledge()` commit batch records in main code but in batch error handler, I am not able to commit offset for invalid messages. I tried `ConsumerAwareBatchErrorHandler` & `BatchErrorHandler` but `isAckAfterHandle()` method or `consumer.commitSync()` are not working.

Issue1: Need to understand the process to acknowledge batch/commit offset.
Issue2: I am getting data as null. I tried to read original message from data (which is null) or thrownexception but failed.

Can Someone please help me with process to commit offset and move to next batch? I am looking to insert failed messages in dead letter or error queue and move on to next batch of messages.

Code tried:

```java
       @Bean
       public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
           Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
           props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
           props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, maxPollRecords);
           props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, maxPollIntervalMsConfig);
           props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
           props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
           props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
           props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
           props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, StringDeserializer.class);
           props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
           props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, JsonDeserializer.class);
           return props;
       }
   
       @Bean
       public DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory consumerFactory() {
           return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer(LocationRecordDto.class));
       }
   
       @Bean(KAFKA_LISTENER)
       public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MyDTO> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
           ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MYDTO> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
           factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
           factory.setBatchListener(true);
           factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
           factory.setBatchErrorHandler(new ConsumerAwareBatchErrorHandler() {
               @Override
               public void handle(Exception thrownException, ConsumerRecords<?, ?> data, Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
      
                   if (thrownException instanceof SerializationException){
                       String s = thrownException.getMessage().split("Error deserializing key/value for partition ")[1].split(". If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.")[0];
                       String topics = s.split("-")[0];
                       int offset = Integer.valueOf(s.split("offset ")[1]);
                       int partition = Integer.valueOf(s.split("-")[1].split(" at")[0]);
   
                       TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topics, partition);
                       consumer.seek(topicPartition, offset + 1);
                   }
                   //Code to push data in error queue
                   //consumer.commitSync();
               }
   
               @Override
               public boolean isAckAfterHandle() {
                   return true;
               }
           });
           return factory;
       }
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: done. @Gary Russell please help me if possible

Answer (score 1):

You have to deal with deserialization exceptions in the listener instead of the error handler and commit the batch offsets normally.

Or consider using the new [RecoveringBatchErrorHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#recovering-batch-eh) instead.